# Joda lib in production

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, android-jodatime

Since Java 8 release, it is recommended to migrate to Java Date APIs. We still continue to support Android API level 23, is it advisable to continue using [Joda](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html) in production?

Comment: Opinions will vary, and there are pros and cons. If maintenance includes touching the code currently using Joda-Time, I would consider desugaring and java.time for API levels from 23 and up.

Comment: Yes, need to consider the effort it takes for migration there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have works then stick with it. Note that Android only supports a subset of the `java.time` API, and you have to do [a bit of setup](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) to get it working at all.

Comment: Good link! I don’t think I agree completely with your first sentence, or it depends for me.